# vba excel, How to rename TextBoxes on userform

Tags: excel, textbox, rename, userform

I have created 112 TextBox on userform.
Please help rename these of them by macro.

```
-TextBox21 - TextBox43 ==> aTextBox21 - aTextBox43
-TextBox44 - TextBox66 ==> bTextBox21 - bTextBox43
-TextBox67 - TextBox89 ==> cTextBox21 - cTextBox43
-TextBox90 - TextBox112 ==> dTextBox21 - dTextBox43
```

Comment: I tried at different module, didn't work. UserForm1.Controls("TextBox").Name = "aTextBox"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs a VBProject reference set for "Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3" and "Trust access to the Visual Basic Project" checked in the Trust Center options.

```
Dim f

Set f = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1")

f.Designer.Controls("TextBox1").Name = "blah"
```

Comment: This is amazing answer, now I got perfect answer, I appreciate it, Tim.